# How can I remove fish from my aquarium?

Tags: petz-dogz-2

How can I remove fish from my aquarium in Petz Dogs 2 without losing them and setting them free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Petz Dogs 2 when the box for the "place fish in  Aquarium" pops up it reads.

> Are you sure you want to place this (enter fish name here) in your aquarium? This is not reversible!

If you accept you will have your fish in the aquarium. Nowwhen you try to remove fish from the aquarium the notice says:

> Are you sure you want to remove (fish name) from your aquarium. You will lose it forever.

So long story short you can't remove any fish without losing them. I would advise you just sell off minor fish and keep large swordfish and sunfish.

Comment: Thanks so much. The smaller fish should have definitely been sold off.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to do this.